# How do I reset a data structure every 24 hours in Android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on a goals app where users can upload their goals and set a target (daily, weekly, monthly)
Now I am facing a problem. I want to reset, lets call it the COUNTER VARIABLE or GOAL DATA STRUCTURE every 24 hours or every week. How would I do this? I am think of **Alarm Manager** approach, but is there any other way? Please provide a code snippet if there is and an explanation will be really appreciated.

***Also I want the change to be reflected online. What if the user has his internet off?***

Answer (score 1):

Alarm Manager is the best option for this.

This is how you can implement it in your App..

Add this in your Main Activity

```
AlarmManager alarmManager;
PendingIntent pi;


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Service.class);

        pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);

        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        final int time = 86400; //24 hours

        if (alarmManager != null) {
            alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, (time * 1000), time * 1000, pi);
        }
```

Create Service Class.

public class Service extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {

 //your code 

}
```

Define receiver in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".Services.Service" />
```

It will definitely work after every 24 hours..

Comment: but what if i need the change to be reflected online but the user has his internet off?

Comment: @EshwarNE You should give this kind of task to a client, it seems like your design is flawed, in any case you can check for the internet connection and in case of absence you can delay the changes on the server. Thus you should perform these operations from server side and then make client asks for updates when it is online

Comment: @Thecave3 you mean "you should not give"?

Comment: @EshwarNE it looks like your client is updating a control that can be easily managed by a server. This is not a good design because you're giving the client to power to update and alter the data indiscriminately. If the main responsible of this update is the server then you don't have the need of  this question at all. You should review your logic.

- Yes you should "not", lol

Comment: @EshwarNE as i told you, you can put you code in onReceive .

Comment: @EshwarNE and you can use SQLite to store data when its offline and send data to serve when user come online.